# How to use Code first Migration for Primary Key?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

At the biginning, I defined the model like this:

```
public class Category
{
  public long CategoryId { get; set;}
  public string CategoryName { get; set; } 
  public virtual ICollection<ContentInfo> Contents { get; set; }
}

Public class Article
{
  public int ContentId { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("Category")]
  public long CategoryId { get; set; }
  public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

After generating the database from the model with Automatic-Migration, I changed the  CategoryId's type from "long" to "int", and update the database with Automatic-Migration again.

This time an exception was throwed, telling me The column "CategoryId" was referenced by Primary key and Foreign Key, so the migration is failed. If i delete the Primary key and Foreign Key manually, everything is ok. but i want the Automatic-Migration to do this for me, can it?

Answer (score 0):

Havent tries such a migration myself, but i recall seeing an option

public class MYMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration
    {

```
    public MyMigrationConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; //have you tried this ?


    }
```

Otherwise you may need to do a code based migration for this type of change

Comment: Yes, I've tried this. but it doesn't solved the problem. The problem is migration just excute the sql `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Category] ALTER COLUMN [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL`, but didn't deleted the constraint first, I wonder if it can do this.

Comment: Thats where the code based migration helps. Classes with the migrations steps are generated.  You tweak these classes, which could involve dropping the constraint and re-adding in a subsequent operation

Comment: so I know to avoid key changes until im ready to use code based migrations.  :-) Thx

Comment: Hmm, it seems this is the only way i can do, but it's inconvenient. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: here a good start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621     BTW did you try manually removing the FK on db and in the code before trying the migration? Then re-add it in code afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Sever Explore" and manually manipulate the table structure, e.g., dropping the key constraints, or delete the whole table. And let EF to generate the brand new table definitions.